# How to read one field in a firestore sub collection using flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

In my code I tried to fecth age filed from users table using userID. Structure of database.

[image]

childPrivateDetails is a subcollection of user table

**I want to fetch age from this table  how to do that and pass when click next button should pass the age to "void ageCa()" method **

code

```
class _GuideLineScreenState extends State<GuideLineScreen> {
  Future<void> getAge() async {
    final sp = context.read<SignInProvider>();
    Future<void> getAge() async {
      final path = 'users/${sp.uid}/childPrivateDetails/${sp.uid}';
      final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path);
      final age = await reference.get().then((value) => value.get('age'));
      print('age is: $age');
    }
  }
```

next button code

```
SizedBox(
                      width: 160.0,
                      height: 35.0,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                          shape:
                              MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                              side: const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          ageCa();
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'next',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

void ageCa() code

```
void ageCa() {
    String age = age;
    final data = age.split(",");
    final List<int> numbers =
        data.map((e) => int.parse(e.replaceAll(RegExp('[^0-9]'), ''))).toList();

    //format "Years: 2, Months: 00, Days: 00"; only work on this format
    Duration ageDuration =
        Duration(days: numbers[0] * 365 + numbers[1] * 30 + numbers[2]);

    if (ageDuration >= const Duration(days: 2 * 288)) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()),
      );
    } else {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const HomeScreen(),
          ));
    }
  }
```

For this, I didn't use model
path image
[image]

User ID in console
[image]

code
[image]

I added print($age); at the Widget build(BuildContext context) {
[image]

void ageCa()
[image]

Comment: What the `age` on the righthand side of this supposed to be: `String age = age;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `get()` method to fetch single field like so:

```html
Future<void> getAge() async {
    final uid = IZf3qxWtmxcWF6oXh1nbB8SK4az2
    final path = 'users/$uid/childPrivateDetails/$uid';
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path);
    final age = await reference.get().then((value) => value.get('age'));
    print('age is: $age');
  }
```

Comment: bro still nothing displayed in the console I will be add in question what I actually want to do

Comment: it might be a problem from your path...make sure your path is correct. if you can get the document using your path then my code is wrong. but if you can't query the doc then your path is wrong.

Comment: can you able to print the `sp.uid` ?are you sure sp.uid and the doc id is match?

Comment: please print `sp.uid` in your console and let me know what comes out.

Comment: okay I will edit the question

Comment: i edited the code to make sure the path is correct. try it again

Comment: i saw how you implemented my code. which is the reason why its not working. you shouldnt be nesting the `getAge()` function to another getAge(). you should run the code as is don't nest it in any other function.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(sp.uid)
        .collection("childPrivateDetails")
        .doc(sp.uid)
        .get(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    }

   return Text(snapshot.data.data()!["age"]);
  },
),
```

Comment: bro I tried it but not worked , Nothing display in console

Comment: I will update my code

Comment: I tried both 1st one not worked And I added 2nd one then display this error .I  Edited the question

Comment: bro still nothing displayed in the console I will be add in question what I actually want to do

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, firebase document snapshoot have just function `.data()` not an `.data.data()` Your error is highlighting that `.data()` not exists, and it is because `.data` before `.data()` is a function not a variable. I might be wrong, I'm not a swift programmer. Give me a call if I'm wrong and your snapshot returns something like variable `.data`.